# What is wrong with this line of code?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I've been trying to start a Minecraft server. I read a small guide and followed the steps, until I tried to run this code:

```
java -Xmx1G -Xms200M -jar minecraft_server.exe nogui
pause
```

I keep getting the Windows script reader error code "*800A0401*", accompanied with the message "*Expected end of statement*". What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Does nogui need a hyphen? I'm no expert on servers but seeing as it's an argument passed to the server, it probably does.

Comment: Can you link the guide you used?

Comment: @AMJ it does not.

Comment: @Wildingmango24 The Minecraft server is distributed as a JAR, not an EXE. What are you trying to run?

Comment: The guide I used was the top voted comment on this other post:https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226079/how-to-change-a-singleplayer-world-into-a-multiplayer-world?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

The guide you linked is wrong in two ways.

1. It suggests, that the server is distributed in an exe file format, while it is usually a file named `server.jar`
2. It saves the start script with the `vbs` extension instead of `bat`.

### The correct way

1. Obtain the server executable from the [official site](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/).
   **Note**: This guide assumes, that the downloaded file is called `server.jar`. If not, you should rename it.
2. Type the following text into a notepad, and save it as `start.bat` in the same folder as your server executable jar-file.
   **Note**: You can change the amount of memory allocated to your server by changing the values after `Xmx` and `Xms`. `Xmx` sets the maximum amount of used RAM, `Xms` sets the amount of RAM allocated on start. It is recommended for the two to have the same value, but it isn't required. Append `M` to the value to indicate megabytes, or `G` to indicate gigabytes.

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui
pause
```

3. (After this you can follow the original guide.)
   Run the `start.bat` file, and you'll get an eula.txt file. Open it, and change the last `false` to `true`. Save and run the file again.
4. Now the server files should've generated, and the basic setup should be done. You might want to change some settings in the server.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

The command should look like this:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.1.15.2.jar nogui
pause
```

Yours didn't look like this, specifically this part:

```
-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
```

There are a few other possible reasons why this didn't work. One obvious one is that you didn't install Java. Another one would be that you might have not set the EULA to 'true'. The last one I can think of is you don't have the .JAR extension showing up. If it doesn't, in File Explorer, at the top tabs, click on View. Then, check "File name extensions". If you don't understand, see the image below:

[image: View > File name Extensions]

Comment: that's wrong @nishantc1527

Comment: Even if not: why would it be right? We expect answers here to explain why something is like it is.

Comment: I know it's correct because I launched my own server with this. But anyways, I will add an explanation.

Comment: `-Xmx` and `-Xms` mean how much RAM the server can use (Xmx), and how much will get allocated on start (Xms)
You can set them to any value